# Why is a ZFS pool not persisting over server restart?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, zfs, zpool

I have a ZFS pool with 4 drives. It also has a 3gb ZIL and a 20GB L2ARC that are each partitions on an SDD that doubles as my Linux Mint (ver. 13) boot drive. The pool is mounted to /data.

The problem I am running into is that when I restart the server the pool/directory is completely wiped despite having data in it prior.  I'm afraid I'm doing something wrong in the setup, which leads me to the following questions:

1. What would cause this?
2. Is there anyway to get the data back?
3. How do I stop it from happening in the future?

Thank you in advance!

> pool: data
>
> state: ONLINE
>
> scan: none
>
> requested config:

```
NAME        STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
data        ONLINE       0     0     0
  raidz2-0  ONLINE       0     0     0
    sda1    ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdb1    ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdc1    ONLINE       0     0     0
    sdd1    ONLINE       0     0     0
logs
  sde4      ONLINE       0     0     0
cache
  sde3      ONLINE       0     0     0
```

errors: No known data errors

**Edit**

It looks like it thinks my boot partition is also full when it shouldn't be. The numbers aren't adding up (see screenshot).

[image: hdd]

Comment: Try removing your L2ARC and ZIL from the pool and testing to see if pool data persists across reboots.

Comment: Yea, no go. Although it did survive a restart, I logged in with a different user and the files were gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how this happened but apparently a directory named "data" existed on my filesystem. When I destroyed the zpool, the directory and the files were visible.

I don't know if exporting/importing with a new name caused a mkdir call to happen out of sequence or what but I double checked to make sure there wasn't a dir with the same name as te pool before creating it.

Anyway, it's working without a hitch now.